# How capture dynamically populated dropdown list ids in Capybara

Tags: ruby, capybara

I am using Capybara,Rspec and Ruby for my development. I am having drop down list which is populated with values with dynamic ids because of which I am not able locate the element correctly. Here is HTML code. I tried to get the solution from this site as well as by googling. But I couldn't get the correct solution

when I am doing the firebug I am getting Xpath as //*[@id='select2-result-label-8'] and every time I am getting new id in the last meaning, next time if I go I will get it as  //*[@id='select2-result-label-11']. How to resolve this issue. I am having similar issues with my group of check box  also. Hope this solution will help there also

```
<ul id="Values" class="check" role="listbox">
<li class="Reports " role="presentation">
<div id="select2-result-label-3" class="history" role="option">
<span class="same"/>
Add New
</div>
</li>
<li class="Reports-highlighted" role="presentation">
<div id="select2-result-label-4" class="history" role="option">
<span class="same"/>
Multiple
</div>
</li>
<li class="Reports" role="presentation">
<div id="select2-result-label-5" class="history" role="option">
<span class="same"/>
Last
</div>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: WHat is the code that generates that list? where do the ids come from? Which item in your drop-down do you need to select? can you use the non-exact match to select it instead?

Comment: @Taryn I am sorry I didn't gt your question correctly. What I am trying to do is to test the website using Capybara tool for which I can select one of the items that is in drop down list. I am not sure where exactly the ids are coming(May be developers might be knowing

Comment: "I am having drop down list which is populated with values with dynamic ids " - this implies you have a template somewhere where this html is being generated. Show us that code please. :)

Comment: I am using the code to click on element is like below find(:xpath,  //[@id='select2-result-label-8']).click. since the id is generate in a dynamic way, It is giving an error , it is not able to find the element

Comment: Why not select the item by text instead of id? The text seems to be the only unique identifier.

Comment: @user2408070 - you have tagged this question as `ruby` - but you have shown us no ruby code... where is the ruby code that is in your project that is related to this question? You have used the `capybara` tag - but you have not shown us the tests that use capybara. You have talked about it... but now please edit your question and add the code that is relevant. Thanks.